# Javascript popup/alert

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that I would like the user to confirm their order is correct. I get two pop ups this way and only want one that summarises the order and prompts for confirmation with a message.
When the user clicks ok, the popup closes and returns to form for submission (there is a submit button). However, if the user clicks cancel then the form resets and popup closes.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you
Note: This is part of an assessment and required to be done this way even though there are better ways.

// JavaScript Document

```
function display() {
    var x=document.confirm.qty.value; 
    var y=document.confirm.price.value; 
    var z=document.confirm.total.value;
    alert("Quantity:"+x+" \n "+"Price Each:"+y+" \n "+"Total Price:"+z );  

    if(confirm('Confirm your order?'));
}
```

Comment: Could you please include the markup of your form as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking for [`window.confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm). That is the dialog that displays two buttons: OK and Cancel. It also returns a boolean value indicating whether OK or Cancel was selected.

Assuming that your `display` function is an `onSubmit` handler, you could rewrite it like so:

```
function display(event) {
    var x = document.querySelector('[name="qty"]'),
        y = document.querySelector('[name="price"]'),
        z = document.querySelector('[name="total"]');

    // Simplified string creation with ES6 String Interpolation
    var confirm = window.confirm(`
        Quantity: ${x.value}
        Price Each: ${y.value}
        Total Price: ${z.value}
    `);

    if (confirm == true) {
        // All OK
        return;
    } else {
        // Blocking default `submit` event
        event.preventDefault();

        // Resetting form
        x.value = null;
        y.value = null;
        z.value = null;

        return;
    }
}
```

Do not forget to pass in the `event` to the callback:

```
<form onsubmit="display(event);">
```

Comment: To confirm order I have a confirm order button. Submit is separate

Comment: Could you please add the html markup to the question too? Anyway, the main idea would be the same wherever you call `display(event);`. That could be another button too.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
return confirm('...
```

Further make sure the onclick is has return in front of your method name in HTML.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Im still learning so hope I dont sound to dumb. I do appreciate any and all help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Popups are quite uncommon for this use-case. Create a div which overlays the whole site (makes all other things unclickable). In that div create another one which is centered where you ask for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
function display()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('qty').value; 
    var y = document.getElementById('price').value; 
    var z = document.getElementById('total').value;

    var result = confirm('Quantity:' + x + '\nPrice Each: ' + y + '\nTotal Price: ' + z + '\n\nConfirm your order?');
    if(result)
    {
        // user has pressed OK
    }
    else
    {
        // user has pressed cancel
    }
}
```